# How can I instantiate an ImageView at runtime in Android?

Tags: android, runtime, imageview

I have a class that is extending ImageView. I want to instantiate this class run time in my Android activity but can't get it to show. If I on the other hand call it from xml, it shows.

This works:

```
PanelChart pc = (PanelChart) findViewById(R.id.pc);
```

With xml:

```
    <com.example.android.PanelChart android:id="@+id/pc" android:layout_width="30dip" android:layout_height="30dip" 
android:background="@color/marker_color" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
android:layout_marginTop="42dip"/>
```

This doesn't work:

```
 PanelChart pc = new PanelChart(this);
            pc.setParameter(new String(stringParameter));
            pc.setLayoutParams(params);
            pc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                RelativeLayout rel = new RelativeLayout(this);
            rel.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            tr = new TableRow(this);

            tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            rel.addView(pc);
            tr.addView(rel);
            tablelayout.addView(tr);
```

My feeling is I should be able to treat it just like a normal imageView, but why can't I get it to show? Am I missing something?

THanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check your imports at the top of your code you should have

1. `import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams`

For setting the layout parameters in your relative layout and also

1. `import android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams`

for setting the table row layout parameters. Do you have both?

If you do then try setting up the relative layout in your xml then just adding the table layout & rows to that.

Comment: I get the response that the second import collides with the first. Without the second my TableRows don't show, so that is the one I use. Is there another way a to import the params, or maybe use other ones, to get it to show? It seems so easy, I mean, just to instantiate an ImageView runtime shouldn't be so hard?

Comment: I have a LinearLayout that I add the TableLayout to.